# Deadlock inside malloc_atfork

Tags: c, multithreading, malloc, fork

My program is deadlocking and here are the top 4 frames of the deadlock:

```
#0  __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:97
#1  0x00007f926250b7aa in _L_lock_12502 () at malloc.c:3507
#2  0x00007f926250a2df in malloc_atfork (sz=12, caller=<value optimized out>) at arena.c:217
#3  0x00007f926250881a in __libc_calloc (n=<value optimized out>, elem_size=<value optimized out>) at malloc.c:4040
```

I'm leaning towards this being a problem caused by something I'm doing wrong. We see the deadlock when stressing the server and taking it to high usage levels, but otherwise we can't reproduce this. Does anyone know what kind of mistake causes this?

Comment: Is there any possibility for malloc to require really big numbers?(3gb + for example)

Comment: @dheer: Can you show the call stack of all threads at the time of deadlock.From this call stack it looks like this thread is waiting for some lock which is acquired by some other thread.

Comment: It's generally impossible to use `fork()` in a multithreaded program if the child process doesn't immediately overwrite the program image. The typical doomsday scenario involves a multithreaded memory allocator which will break immediately in the forked process.

Comment: It would be helpful to post stack traces for other threads and code around your `fork`/`clone` call sites.

Comment: @KerrekSB: That should probably be an answer.

Comment: There are over 200 other threads in the daemon, but most of them are waiting to acquire a lock held by the thread which is blocking inside the call to calloc.

Answer (score 1):

Per POSIX, after calling `fork` in a multithreaded process, the child process is in an async signal context and undefined behavior is invoked if you do anything other than calling async-signal-safe functions before calling `_exit` or one of the `exec` family functions.

Comment: My program isn't calling fork at this time, it called calloc. There is one fork in the program when it sends email, but the child process only dups, closes file descriptors, calls execv, and then exits if execv returns.

Comment: I just reproduced the same issue, this time the malloc_atfork() call is inside a call to new from my program. In neither of these cases, nor any other where its getting stuck, am I actually calling fork().

Comment: Do you have a minimal test case program to reproduce the issue? If so I can try it and report the bug to glibc if there seems to be a real bug.

Comment: Also, do you have any signal handlers, and is it possible that you're calling `malloc` (possibly indirectly) from a signal handler?

Answer (score 0):

You most frequently get a deadlock if difering execution threads acquire shared resources in a *different* order.  Appearing under stress is a good indicator of this.  Support you have:

```
A == 1 2
B == 2 1
```

Now, suppose you get a thread reschedule right after A acquires `1` but before it grabs `2`.  Thread B runs and acquires `2` and then control returns to A; it is now blocked waiting on resource 2, which is held by B which is waiting for resource 1 held by A.  Now, A cannot proceed and neither can B; deadlock.

Another cause of deadlocks is a slight variation on this, where one execution path claims a resource without honoring the resource locking; this will mislead other execution threads that follow the rules.

Hope this helps.